# Which is the difference between jdbcTemplate.update and jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate?

Tags: java, sql-update

```
public void insert(Post post){
String insertString = "INSERT INTO posts(id, title) VALUES(" + post.getId() + ", \"" + post.getTitle() + "\" + ");";

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertString);
    jdbcTemplate.update(insertString);
}
```

Which one should be used and why?

Comment: isn't the name `batchUpdate` enough to explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoted from Javadoc ;)

- [batchUpdate()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String...-):

  > Issue multiple SQL updates on a single JDBC Statement using batching.
  >   Will fall back to separate updates on a single Statement if the JDBC driver does not support batch updates.
- [update()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-):

  > Issue a single SQL update operation (such as an insert, update or delete statement).